# Popup control is displaying outside the main window

Tags: wpf, popup

I am trying to display emoji list when user clicks on some button. I have given the emoji list in `Popup`.

```
<Grid ClipToBounds="True" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Popup AllowsTransparency="True" ClipToBounds="True" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOffset="0" VerticalOffset="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Placement="RelativePoint" materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <materialDesign:Card VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" UniformCornerRadius="0" Visibility="Visible" materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth1">
                <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="#d2d9d4" BorderThickness="0.6" ClipToBounds="True">
                    <Grid>
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EmojisList}" MaxWidth="350" MaxHeight="450" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <emoji:TextBlock FontSize="25" Text="{Binding .}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </materialDesign:Card>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
```

With the following code, I am getting the popup as following.
[image]

this is how the popup is displaying, actually it should be inside the mainwindow. Please let me how to achieve this.

Comment: Why are you using a `Popup` if you want to content to stay inside the window or grid? Can't you just remove the `Popup` and set the `Visibility` property of the `Grid` instead of setting the `IsOpen` property of the `Popup` whenever you want to display or hide the emoji list? `Popups` do appear on top of the window.

Comment: Yes, but the position must be relative. The box at the bottom can be at any position on window. Hence, the position of emoji grid is not a fixed one. So, I have used popup.

Comment: So what's your issue/question?

Comment: Thanks for the immediate response @mm8, I am just looking forward to make that popup control inside the window else I need the to know some control whose position can be relative and that is similar to popup control.

Comment: Like I have already told you, a popup is never inside a parent window. It's a window of its own.

Comment: In such a case, is there any way to make Grid/any other controls with relative positions ( the position must be like mouse pointer).

Comment: So you want a floating Popup but you want to set a custom position for it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202149/discussion-between-sahithi-and-mm8).

Comment: Yes, looking forward for that.

Comment: Then you need to specify the positon explicitly. Please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/popup-placement-behavior).

Comment: Thank you for the link @mm8 , I will go through it.